# getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(booleanValue)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, appbar

I was trying to implement navigation drawer into my app.

In it I came across this line of code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

but I am not able to understand the meaning of this code.

I tried reading the official documentation but it was not clear?

Comment: Please add the link to the function documentation, and precise what was not clear in it.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines used to enable and show the home button.

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

[image]

You can set your own icon by adding this line: `

> getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon_navigation);

To perform an action on this button you will need to override onOptionItemSelected and put below code inside but make sure you write the correct id many people confuse with it.

> Home button id: android.R.id.home

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home){
                // write your own code..
                return true;
              }
        }   
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Is the menu button in the picture you provided called home button?

Comment: I have added my icon to home button. As I said in my post you can add your own icon

Comment: Inside circle, the button is called home button. Whenever you enable it their default icon will look like this <---